# Помогите найти шрифт похожий на Baloo

Tags: шрифты, веб-дизайн, дизайн, photoshop

Помогите пожалуйста найти шрифт который будет похож на шрифт Baloo. Проблема в том, что Baloo кириллицу не поддерживает, а мне нужен шрифт который поддерживает кириллицу, шрифт у которого на символах не будет острых углов. Пример шрифта Baloo ниже на картинке  [image: Шрифт Baloo]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится ни к программированию, ни системному администрированию.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, ничего похожего пока нет. К самим создателям обращались более года назад с просьбой разработать кириллические символы. Неофициальный ответ: разработайте, а мы включим :)